# What do you call a SQL where condition that is completely within parentheses?

Tags: sql

I have the query below.

```
SELECT  ...
FROM cats
LEFT JOIN mice AS mice ON cats.id = mice.cats_id
WHERE cats.id = 43 AND (((mice.size = 'L') AND (mice.type = 'SP') AND (mice.dying_noise = '')) OR (mice.type IS NULL))
```

What type of clause is this? / Is there a special name for this?

```
(((mice.size = 'L') AND (mice.type = 'SP') AND (mice.dying_noise = '')) OR (mice.type IS NULL))
```

It's working for me in MySql so it may or may not be legal.

Comment: what's the problem here?

Comment: Nothing special. MySQL accepts a logical expression for a `WHERE` cluase. And this is just a logical expression. Logical expressions sometimes have parentheses to help ensure precedence of operation. Google "MySQL logical expressions" for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Expressions like that are called *fully parenthesized*. One can evaluate them correctly without knowing anything about operator precedence, because the order is fully controlled by parentheses.

There is no particular point in making such expressions when the evaluation order that they enforce matches the evaluation order established by default operator precedence rules. Although in many situations you can improve readability by adding parentheses that do not alter the order implied by precedence rules, it rarely makes sense to go all the way to fully parenthesizing your expression.

Fully parenthesized expressions are often created when query conditions are generated automatically by some sort of a program or a library that converts expressions defined through metadata to a SQL string.

Comment: I disagree with the point that "There is no particular point <snip>". Clarity is important. Once you start mixing different operators (and/or, +,*,/,^), I feel it it absolutely important that parentheses are used. It shows explicit intent that the operations are performed in a certain order. Default precedence rules are clear, but they vary between programming languages. Can you be sure the person that wrote it knew the rules and that was their intent?

Comment: @Ghost Of course, adding some extra parentheses to improve readability is a good thing. I was in a situation when a missing pair of parentheses caused a multi-hour delay in testing a large package-handling system, with several dozen package throwers having to sit idly (while being paid an hourly wage!) while my friend and I were fixing the error and rolling it out to production. My point was that it is rare that one would go to fully parenthesized expression, because doing so kills readability fast.

Comment: I agree that there are definitely unnecessary parentheses in the example in the question and agree that using parentheses on every single expressions reduces legibility. I simply felt it was context that needed added. Cheers!